# Scroll Event is called multiple time

Tags: javascript

I have a script that runs on scroll event on whole body
But there is a problem I am getting results on every 30 px scroll (I think it is 30px but I dont know actually)

I wanted to limit the scroll , I also found out some question on firing event on scroll stop but I didn't get a consolidate answer . can someone help please

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: share your code with live demo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try  window.scroolto  or scroolby  see w3school